# What does the term "Task" mean in Android

Tags: android

I am noob in Android, I want to know the meaning of the term "Task" in Android. Here docs using

> A "singleInstance" activity stands alone as the only activity in its task

Is task is Stack ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the definition here : http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html.

Tasks are basically :

> A task is a collection of activities that users interact with when
>   performing a certain job.

Task has the same common meaning than in natural english, it's a task to be done by a user.

Comment: A "singleInstance" activity stands alone as the only activity in its task --- Here only activity in its task meaning ??

Comment: As a task is a collection of activities, a single instance activity means that the task = a collection containing this very single activity.